# Interchange summation order in the limit of number of elements going to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Considering the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{ij}$, in general we are not allowed to interchange the summation order (i.e. pass to $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{ij}$) but some more hypothesis are required to allow the change of order (e.g., by Fubini Theorem, we are allowed if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|<\infty$).

Consider now the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}$ , $N=cL$ , $c \in \mathbb{N}$. Our sum doesn't respect Fubini hypothesis, i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{N=\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{L=\infty} |a_{ij}|=\infty$.

If now we consider the limit sum $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} a_{ij}$, are we allowed then to interchange the summation order, since $\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{L} |a_{ij}|< \infty$  $\forall N<\infty$?

Comment: Assuming $a_{ij}$ are real numbers, the condition $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=0}^L|a_{ij}|<\infty$ is something that always holds and so it does not give any special benefits.

Comment: If $L$ is fixed, then under limit you have the same sum of finitely many terms.

Comment: @mihaild thank for your comment; note that $N=cL , c \in \mathbb{N}$ so if $N\rightarrow \infty$ then also $L \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Anyway, you have the same term-by-term sums under limit in any order. Fubini theorem is actually needed for interchanging not sums, but limits: $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N \lim_{M \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} = \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^M \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N a_{ij}$. In your case you have only one limit, and it doesn't matter how you write the expression under it.

Comment: So in my case, I can say that $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \sum_i^M \sum_j^{cM} a_{ij} =\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \sum_i^{cM} \sum_j^{M} a_{ij} $; is it right?

Comment: There is a typo in the last message; I meant $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \sum_i^M \sum_j^{cM} a_{ij} = \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_j^{cM} \sum_i^M a_{ij}$

Comment: Yes, you can, The term under limit is the same in both cases.